# How to use sequence in a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `test` with columns `(id int, name varchar)`.

I want output as below:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   1
e   2
f   3
```

Comment: Please post your sample Data of your table

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question,I want 1,2,3 sequence corresponding to the alphabet in a row,like if it is a in first row it should be 1,for next row 2,for next 3,for next 1 and so on

Comment: So, name is `a` and id is `1`? and `d` has id `1` too?

Comment: whatever the name it could be its not specific but the sequence number should be genearted in a order 1,2,3..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why there's only 1,2 and 3 and no 4

Comment: If I understand it correctly, below is what you needed,                                                                                                           SELECT  CASE WHEN RowNumber % 3 = 0 THEN 3
             ELSE RowNumber % 3
        END
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNumber ,
                    FirstName ,
                    LastName
          FROM      Emp
        ) A

Comment: are the values in 'name' column unique? Or there might be a duplication?

Answer (score 2):

Create a sequence like:

```
create SEQUENCE id_seq
  AS BIGINT
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 3
  CYCLE
  CACHE 100;
```

Then use this sequence in your select query like below:

```
select NEXT VALUE FOR contacts_seq as ID, Name from TEST
```

Comment: He tagged Sql-Server-2008, in which the Sequence object does not exists

Comment: In typical SQL, the query can be written as SELECT  CASE WHEN RowNumber % 3 = 0 THEN 3
             ELSE RowNumber % 3
        END NewSequence ,
        Id ,
        FirstName ,
        LastName ,
        Sal
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNumber ,
                    *
          FROM      Emp
        ) A